Different trends of thermalization in a collision of electron-ion
I performed a collision of electron-ion with using initial tmeperature of electron as $T_{e0}=$ 20 eV, ion as $T_{i0}=$ 10 eV and distributing with Maxwellian distribution of velocity. The density of electron and ion assumes equal and constant over collisions ($n_{i}=n_{e}$). The collision particles will collide and then exchange momentum to each other. I plotted the simulation results of energy relaxation compared to the solution of energy relaxation. The euqation of the energy relaxation expressed that:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\left( T_{i}-T_{e}\right)}{\mathrm{d}\nu_{\mathrm{ei}}t} = -2 \nu_{\mathrm{eq}}\left( T_{i}-T_{e}\right), \label{eq:1} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
which $T_{\mathrm{e}}$, $T_{\mathrm{i}}$, and $t$ are temperature of electron, temperature of ion, and simulation time. The equilibrium frequency, $\nu_{\mathrm{eq}}$, is given by
\begin{equation*}
\nu_{\mathrm{eq}}=\frac{8}{3\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{m_{e}}{m_{i}}\left( 1+ \frac{m_{e}T_{i0}}{m_{i}T_{e0}} \right)^{-3/2}\nu_{ie}, \label{eq:2} \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
and the frequency of e-i collision is given by
\begin{equation*}
\nu_{ie}  \equiv \frac{2}{3\sqrt{\pi}}n_{i}\frac{q_{e}^{2}q_{i}^{2}}{\left(4\pi\epsilon_{0}\right)^{2}}\frac{4\pi}{m_{e}^{1/2}T_{e}^{3/2}} \ln \Lambda_{e}, \label{eq:3} \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where $\ln \Lambda_{e}$ is Coulomb logarithm of e-i collision.
The simulation that I've been working based on paring electron with random ion and iterate for $N$ particles. After that the momentum exchange will be determined by Nanbu method for Coulomb Collision
However, when I constructed the analytic soloution and plotted compared to the simulation results, the plotting result was surprised me like a picture below. Could anyone suggest me to find answer or improve my numerical process?


You should calculate the percent difference or something like that between the analytical and simulation results.  Then you should check the numerical accuracy of the calculations in the simulation.  If this a PIC simulation, the number of particles-per-cell, for instance, can greatly affect the accuracy of velocity moment calculations.  In short, there are so many things "under the hood" in any given simulation it may not be possible to answer your question.

@honeste_vivere
Thanks so much for your suggestions. I looked in my code again and found that velocities of each particle specie were not picked up randomly and identically. So, I improve my code by using different random numbers for each particle in each species. I also found similar features of energy relaxation between simulation and analytic solutions.

I see that your analytical solution over time has trend like $\propto 1/t$, but your numerical solution has trend order like $\propto 1/{\ln t}$, i.e. asymptotically approaches infinity when $t \to 0$. Seems you are using different models for simulation and analytical solution.

@AgniusVasiliauskas It seems like my analytic solution depends on the term $\exp(-t)$ instead $1/t$, If you have further more explanation, please kindly give the details.

Hm.. it's strange then, because usually exponential behavior is more steep, than your $f(t)$ analytical routine, but maybe I'm wrong because I just tried a couple of charts in DESMOS to try and re-create your curves behavior. Ok, then. What about numerical model, - what is your simulated/numerical function dependence $f_{num}(t) \propto ?$ My main point is that you are using different  $T(t)$ models in simulated and analytical parts, because curves differs radically. Check your models once again.

@AgniusVasiliauskas My numerical model based on Nanbu algorithm of plasma. The algorithm will exchange velocity corresponding to accumative scattering angles. The acculative scattering angles were calculated from the isotropic scattering parameter, which are correspondig to Coulomb logarithm, collision frequency, temperature and density of the system.   In each iteration step, the velocity of eavh particle will change due to scattering angles. After that, I can compute temperatures from velocities after collisions. I think I'm not answering you not but these are details of my numerical model.
